# Issue with Generating PDF from Long Html string using itextsharp

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I have a requirement to generate a PDF from HTML that contains a table with  almost 2000 rows. When I am trying to generating the PDF, it's generating up to 250 rows then skipping the other rows and HTML content and only generating 6 pages. What may cause the issue?

```
string HtmlStream="Some large content", string FileName="abcd.pdf";

object TargetFile = FileName;
string ModifiedFileName = string.Empty;
string FinalFileName = string.Empty;
ModifiedFileName = TargetFile.ToString();
ModifiedFileName = ModifiedFileName.Insert(ModifiedFileName.Length - 4, "1");
SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();

// set converter options
string pdf_page_size = "A4";
SelectPdf.PdfPageSize pageSize = (SelectPdf.PdfPageSize)Enum.Parse(typeof(SelectPdf.PdfPageSize),
 pdf_page_size, true);

converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pageSize;
converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = SelectPdf.PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
converter.Options.MarginLeft = 10;
converter.Options.MarginRight = 10;
converter.Options.MarginTop = 10;
converter.Options.MarginBottom = 10;
converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime = 1000;

// create a new pdf document converting an url
SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(HtmlStream);

doc.Save(ModifiedFileName.ToString());
```

Comment: Your tags say iTextSharp but your code says SelectPdf. Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to do this with iTextSharp?

Comment: I'm un-tagging as iTextSharp because I don't see any relationship with it.